# Is C# Process re-escaping characters in string read from R script output?

Tags: c#, r, process, streamreader, rscript

I am trying to read an Json output from R script, my R file (RScript.R) looks like this :

```
cat("[{\"code\":0,\"message\":\"FILE1.xls has been successfully checked.\"}]")
```

I created in C# a method that runs the R script that looks like this:

```
    public static string RunRScript(string scriptpath)
    {
        string result, errResult;
        try
        {
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = RExeFolder,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(RExeFolder),
                Arguments = scriptpath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            using (var proc = new Process { StartInfo = info })
            {
                proc.Start();
                result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                errResult = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do something with error
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

The output looks fine when I run it in cmd, meaning with no "\" :
[image]

But the issue occurs when I want to read the output from C#, I have a WEB Api that calls the **RunRScript** method and returns the string and the output looks like this:

[image]

I tried to check at the moment of reading the output from the scriptand it looks the same as in the API, with the double quotes escaped:

[image]

**Questions:**

- Is there something I`m doing wrong?
- Is C# re-escaping the double
  quotes?